# Application hangs in SysUtils -> DoneMonitorSupport on exit

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

I am writing a very thread intensive application that hangs when it exits.

I've traced into the system units and found the place where the program enters an infinite loop. It's in **SysUtils** line 19868 -> **DoneMonitorSupport** -> **CleanEventList**:

```
repeat until InterlockedCompareExchange(EventCache[I].Lock, 1, 0) = 0;
```

I've searched for a solution online and found a couple of QC reports:

- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=95194
- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90487

Unfortunately, these don't seem to relate to my situation as I don't use either **TThreadList** or **TMonitor**.

I'm pretty sure that all my threads have finished and have been destroyed as that all inherit from a base thread that keeps a create/destroy count.

Has anybody come across similar behaviour before? Do you know of any strategies for discovering where the root cause may lie?

Comment: Didn't XE2 make all objects monitor objects somehow? Thus it could be any object that is being locked. It may be worth checking for leaks, but that may need the app to finish to tell you...

Comment: You don't but something *might* use `TMonitor`. Link your application with debug units, put a brakepoint in `TMonitor.Enter` and wait.

Comment: The RTL uses `TMonitor`. For example `TThread.Synchronize`. Which XE2 update are you on.

Comment: @CosminPrund - Yepp, TMonitor is call a LOT even though I never use it explicitly.

Comment: There's an other bug in the shut-down sequence of `TThread` descendants that may cause a race-condition and hang on application shut-down. I discovered that because I wrote my own "thread pool" and upon completion I would set all threads to Terminate then wake them all up using an Event. My solution was to shut down threads one-by-one, wait until the first thread was down before shutting down the next. I think the app used to hang in `TThread.Destroy`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes, I'm seeing Synchronize use TMonitor. I'm on XE2 Update 4 Hotfix 1.

Comment: `TMonitor` is, excuse me, pure crap. Can't help but ask how it got through Quality Assurance. I've got a 60 line demo console application that hangs on exit, and if you look at the code, I'm not even doing anything fancy: I'm basically exercising the *obvious* way of using it.

Comment: @CosminPrund - I destroy all my threads before allowing the application to exit. I don't seem to have any issues destroying threads.

Comment: There must be something *in your threads* that's calling `TMonitor`, because it only fails if you run it from 2 threads at the same time (race condition). If you have the patience, that's what you should be looking for, the application stopping in `TMonitor.Enter` when called from a Thread, not the VCL thread.

Comment: @CosminPrund It's `TThread.Synchronize`

Comment: `TThread.Synchronize` can be avoided; I don't even have *one* in all my threads.

Comment: @CosminPrund We aren't talking about your code. We are talking about Norwegian Paul's code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, we're not talking about my code, that was just an example. If not using `TThread.Synchronize` is the ticket to solving this, the the Synchrnoization can be done using some other mechanism. I'm suggesting removing all code that causes calls to `TMonitor.Enter`, because the alternative is fixing `TMonitor.Enter/Exit`, and that's out of our hands.

Comment: @CosminPrund, can you somehow provide your 60 line demo console application exposing the said error? Just curious.

Comment: @UweRaabe: http://pastebin.com/eGKzNa3i - I coud make it 50 lines by removing whitespace and comments :) Compiled with Delphi 2010 and Delphi XE2 targeting both Win 32bit and Win 64bit.

Comment: I haven't used TThread.Syncronize since I first had an issue with it on D3 and looked at how it worked.  I'm now adding TMonitor to my blacklist.  I'll stick to PostMessage - I used it at D3 and, of course, being a Windows API, it has worked without any changes on all Delphi versions since.  As for terminating secondary threads on app exit - no longer do it, (since a long time), it just causes problems.

Comment: @CosminPrund, your code hangs in `repeat until AtomicCmpExchange(EventCache[I].Lock, 1, 0) = 0;` in `SysUtils` routine `DoneMonitorSupport` in XE3. This is when cleaning the event list.

Comment: In Delphi 2010 and Delphi XE2 my code hangs exactly where the OP's code hangs. On Delphi XE3 it seems the code got rewritten somehow, but the bug has not been fixed. I don't have XE3 to see for myself. My code is *dead simple*, it's one of the many things the Quality Assurance should have used to test.

Comment: @CosminPrund, did you make a report to QC of this? Seems like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @LURD, I have not. Looking around the QC site for the "Submit" button.

Comment: Login and follow this [link](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?da=42). On top there is `Add report in this area`. There is also a QC client inside the IDE, less user friendly though (SIC).

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111795

Comment: @CosminPrund, the problem shown by your example goes away when you free SyncObj after the threads are done.

Comment: @UweRaabe, notived that... after digging up all the code for `TMonitor` accross `System` and `SysUtils` unit, after creating a replacement provider for `TMonitor` that allowed me to pin-point the fact that exactly one instance per Object got lost; Then I've done stack-fingerprinting (because I can't change the System) unit to figure out where the calls that create the events that never got free originated from. But I did learn something new, and I do think it's a bug, as I explain in my extra-long answer. The penalty for not freeing an object shouldn't be that high.

Comment: I recently encountered this issue. In my case a component owned a threadlist and I wasn't freeing the component. Ultimately that led to the same problem because TThreadList uses TMonitor internally for it's locks. As Cosmin said, the penalty for not freeing an object should definitely not be that high. It's also not the easiest thing to track down.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've been looking at how the `TMonitor` locks are implemented, and I finally made an interesting discovery. For a bit of drama, I'll first tell you how the locks work.

When you call any `TMonitor` function on an `TObject`, a new instance of the `TMonitor` record is created and that instance is assigned to a `MonitorFld` inside the object itself. This assignment is made in a thread-safe way, using `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer`. Because of this trick the `TObject` only contains one pointer-size amount of data for the support of `TMonitor`, it doesn't contain the full TMonitor structure. And that's a good thing.

This `TMonitor` structure contains a number of records. We'll start with the `FLockCount: Integer` field. When the first thread uses `TMonitor.Enter()` on any object, this combined lock-counter field will have the value ZERO. Again using a `InterlockedCompareExchange` method the lock is acquired and the counter is initiated. There will be no locking for the calling thread, no context-switch since this is all done in-process.

When the second thread tries to `TMonitor.Enter()` the same object, it's first attempt to lock will fail. When that happens Delphi follows two strategies:

- If the developer used `TMonitor.SetSpinCount()` to set a number of "spins", then Delphi will do a busy-wait loop, spinning the given number of times. That's very nice for tiny locks because it allows acquiring the lock without doing a context-switch.
- If the spin-count expires (or there's no spin-count, and by default the spin count zero), `TMonitor.Enter()` will initiate a Wait on the event returned by `TMonitor.GetEvent()`. In other words it will not busy-wait wasting CPU cycles. Remember the `TMonitor.GetEvent()` because that's very important.

Let's say we've got a thread that acquired the lock and a thread that tried to acquire the lock but is now waiting on the event returned by `TMonitor.GetEvent`. When the first thread calls `TMonitor.Exit()` it will notice (via the `FLockCount` field) that there is at least one other thread blocking. So it immediately pulses what should normally be the previously allocated event (calls `TMonitor.GetEvent()`). But since the two threads, the one that calls `TMonitor.Exit()` and the one that called `TMonitor.Enter()` might actually call `TMonitor.GetEvent()` at the same time, tehre are a couple more tricks inside `TMonitor.GetEvent()` to make sure that *only one* event is allocated, irrelevant of the order of operations.

For a few more fun moments we'll now delve into the way the `TMonitor.GetEvent()` works. This thing lives inside the `System` unit (you know, the one we can't recompile to play with), but it turns out it delegates the duty of actually allocated the Event to an other unit, through the `System.MonitorSupport` pointer. That points to a record of type `TMonitorSupport` that declares 5 function pointers:

- `NewSyncObject` - allocates a new Event for Synchronization purposes
- `FreeSyncObject` - deallocates the Event allocated for Synchronization purposes
- `NewWaitObject` - allocates a new Event for Wait operations
- `FreeWaitObject` - deallocates that Wait event
- `WaitAndOrSignalObject` - well.. waits or signals.

It also turns out that the objects returned by the `NewXYZ` functions could be anything, because they're only used for the call to `WaitXYZ` and for the corresponding call to `FreeXyzObject`. The way those functions are implemented in `SysUtils` is designed to provide those locks with a minimum amount of locking and context-switching; Because of that the objects themselves (returned by `NewSyncObject` and `NewWaitObject`) are not directly the Events returned by `CreateEvent()`, but pointers to records in the `SyncEventCacheArray`. It goes even further, actual Windows Events are not created until required. Because of that the records in the `SyncEventCacheArray` contains a couple of records:

- `TSyncEventItem.Lock` - this tells Delphi rather the Lock is being used for anything right now or not and
- `TSyncEventItem.Event` - this holds the actual Event that'll be used for synchronization, if waiting is required.

When the application terminates, the `SysUtils.DoneMonitorSupport` goes over all the records in the `SyncEventCacheArray` and waits for the Lock to become ZERO, ie, waits for the lock to stop being used by anything. Theoretically, as long as that lock is NOT Zero, at least one thread out there might be using the lock - so the sane thing to do would be to wait, in order to NOT cause AccessViolations errors. And we finally got to our current question: HANGING in `SysUtils.DoneMonitorSupport`

## Why an application might Hang in SysUtils.DoneMonitorSupport even if all it's threads terminated properly?

Because at least one Event allocated using any one of `NewSyncObject` or `NewWaitObject` was not freed using it's corresponding `FreeSyncObject` or `FreeWaitObject`. And we go back to the `TMonitor.GetEvent()` routine. The Event it allocates is saved in the `TMonitor` record that corresponds to the object that was used for `TMonitor.Enter()`. The pointer to that record is *only* kept in that object's instance data, and is kept there for the life of the application. Searching for the name of the field, `FLockEvent`, we find this in the `System.pas` file:

```
procedure TMonitor.Destroy;
begin
  if (MonitorSupport <> nil) and (FLockEvent <> nil) then
    MonitorSupport.FreeSyncObject(FLockEvent);
  Dispose(@Self);
end;
```

and a call to that record-destructor in here: `procedure TObject.CleanupInstance`.

In other words, the final sync-event is *only released when the object that was used for synchronization is freed!*

## Answer to OP's question:

The application hangs because at least one OBJECT that was used for `TMonitor.Enter()` was not freed.

## Possible solutions:

Unfortunately I don't like this. It's not right, I mean the penalty for not freeing a small object should be a small memory leak, not a hanging application! This is especially bad for Service applications where a service might simply hang for ever, not fully shut down but unable to respond to any request.

The solutions for the Delphi team? They should NOT hang in the finalization code of the `SysUtils` unit, no-matter-what. They should probably ignore the `Lock` and move to closing the Event handle. At that stage (finalization of the SysUtils unit), if there's still code running in some thread, it's in a real bad shape as most of the units got finalized, it's not running in the environment it was designed to run in.

For the delphi users? We can replace the `MonitorSupport` with our own version, one that doesn't do those extensive tests at finalization time.

Comment: Superb answer Cosmin. At least now I have an idea of what I'm looking for. I guess there's no way to pinpoint which object wasn't free from within DoneMonitorSupport.

Comment: NorgePaul, you could change the code in `DoneMonitorSupport` to avoid the hanging. Set the `ReportMemoryLeakOnShutDown` to true on startup and when the application closes your object leak would appear in the report.

Comment: You could change the `DoneMonitorSupport` as in you could change it in the SysUtils unit and recompile, but that's not pretty. I'd attempt patching it at run-time, replace the code with a `RET` instruction, but that would be very difficult as the code is in the private section of the `SysUtils` unit, it'd be a little bit difficult getting hold of the pointer to the unit.

Comment: Well, what a surprise - a problem in Delphi thread support.  There seems to be a general, (ie. not just Delphi), desire to write complex, buggy shutdown code that tries to explicitly clean up absolutely everything on app shutdown.  This is very difficult to get right on non-trivial multithreaded apps and, for about 30 years, I have been shouting 'JUST DON'T DO IT - LET THE OS CLEAN UP'.   Synchronize, WaitFor, OnTerminate etc seem to conspire to cause shutdown problems, now TMonitor is added on, <sigh>.  Customers don't care about clean valgrind dumps, they just want apps to close when told.

Comment: Put another way - someone shoot the ex-java developer at Embarcadero.

Comment: The [`QC 99324 "Process hangs on shutdown after using TMonitor to wait on an object that isn't freed"`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=99324) seems to be related to this problem as well. Reported 2011-09-26.

Comment: @MartinJames what if your module unloads before process termination? For example runtime linked DLL.

Comment: You can hook the DoneMonitorSupport and copy its content in hooked function. It would be much easier then recompile. I have a hooking unit in my library. Its called Cromis.Detours. Its very easy to use. Look at: http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/

Comment: @Runner You can't hook DoneMonitorSupport because it's private.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your problem using the example provided by Cosmin. I could also solve the problem by simply freeing the SyncObj after all threads are done.

As I have no access to your code, I cannot say more, but probably some object instance used by TMonitor isn't freed.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around the bug in the following way:

Copy **System.SysUtils**, **InterlockedAPIs.inc** and **EncodingData.inc** to my application directory and alter the following code in **System.SysUtils**:

```
  procedure CleanEventList(var EventCache: array of TSyncEventItem);
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    for I := Low(EventCache) to High(EventCache) do
    begin
      if InterlockedCompareExchange(EventCache[I].Lock, 1, 0) = 0 then
         DeleteSyncWaitObj(EventCache[I].Event);
      //repeat until InterlockedCompareExchange(EventCache[I].Lock, 1, 0) = 0;
      //DeleteSyncWaitObj(EventCache[I].Event);
    end;
  end;
```

I also added this check at the top of System.SysUtils to remind me to update the System.SysUtils file if I change Delphi versions:

```
{$IFNDEF VER230}
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
You need to update this unit to fix the bug at line 19868
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217735/application-hangs-in-sysutils-donemonitorsupport-on-exit
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
{$ENDIF}
```

After these changes my application shuts down correctly.

Note: I tried adding "ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown" as LU RD suggested, but on shutdown my app entered a race condition popping up numerous runtime error dialogs. A similar thing happens when I try EurekaLog's memory leak functionality.

Comment: To find a longer term solution you may want to add some logging to your version of NewSyncObj and FreeSyncObj. You can use that to determine which objects are being locked and not released.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi XE5, Embarcadero solved this by adding `(Now - Start > 1 / MSecsPerDay) or` to the `repeat until` loop in `CleanEventList` so that it will give up after 1 millisecond.  It then deletes the event regardless of whether `Lock` was `0`.