# Application hangs in SysUtils -> DoneMonitorSupport on exit Delphi XE4

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe4

i have the same problem like here
[Application hangs in SysUtils -> DoneMonitorSupport on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217735/application-hangs-in-sysutils-donemonitorsupport-on-exit)

in Delphi XE4.

My application is over 700000 rows and i cannot post the complete application here.
The application hangs in DoneMonitorSupport in a repeat until loop. I have no idea to get the object which isn't freed.
With Delphi 2009 the source is ok.
Is there any way to switch off the standard MonitorSupport, so that the application runs like in Delphi 2009?

Comment: If you cannot make a small reproducible case, maybe this "Monitoring the Monitor" post can help: it explains how the Delphi <= XE4 TMonitor implementation can be very slow under certain circumstances http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2013/08/23/38952 There seem to be some fixes in Delphi XE5 for this. I need to research those further before I can write an answer which will take a couple of days because of some other obligations.